# Connection pool leakage with jBPM6 transactional tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jbpm

Environment : `jBPM 6.0.1.Final, jboss EAP 6.2,spring data jpa 1.4.3.RELEASE,hibernate 4.1.1.Final,spring 4.0.0.RELEASE`

I'm facing connection pooling leakage issue with jBPM6 tables and hibernate is firing 50+ queries to complete a single task.  Let me explain you clearly.

In my application I'm performing DML operations on application related tables, I'm observing the connection realeasing machanism by debug as

> DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool]
>   (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-4) mysqlDS: returnConnection(3492713e, false)
>   [1/20]

Connection pooling mechanism works fine and then I submitted a task to be completed by jbpm,some data inserting into jbpm6 tables like `SessionInfo`, `Task` and when data inserted,connection is not releasing and for next task also it is not using opened connections and opening new connections and go on.. Finally I'm getting the following message due to jbpm6 tables.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/mysqlDS
>   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:147)
>   at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
>   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
>   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
>           ... 111 more

I'm using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` for session and transaction which is working for tables i insert data. But not working for data inserting by jbpm6.

I configured `<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/>` as well but not useful to get the connection back.

```
<!--Following entity manager for Mysql database-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="masterDataMysql"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Transaction manager for both H2 and Mysql-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

[Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw440b_26lXbQUJsSlFMZ3JwM0U/view?usp=sharing) For error log

**UPDATE :** This is happening due to connections are not closing by jBPM6

Please help how to solve connection leaking issue with jbpm6 ???
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is no log file at the `Click here` link, only a text file repeating what you have above.

Comment: My apology for mistake, please click and download the log file.